# C++ How to break a while find loop?

Tags: c++, string, loops, while-loop, find

In this loop I want to add new line (\n) behind evert dot(.).

How to break the loop when new line has been added after each dot?

```
while (alltxt.find(".") != string::npos)
    alltxt.replace(alltxt.find("."), 1, ".\n");
```

Comment: You need to have a condition that eventually ends.

Comment: You need to record the position the dot was found in and start the next search from there.

Comment: @Galik have read about it, but haven't really understood how it is done. Never used that kind of search. So thats the only way?

Comment: @Thesar The problem is you are replacing the first `'.'` with `".\n"` and then restarting the search from the start. You then find the same dot every time.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes I know, but I dont understand how I can get out of that loop so it doesnt search the entire string all the time.

Comment: @Thesar Your problem is not getting out of the loop. It would do that automatically if the body of your loop was correct. Your problem is that your algorithm's logic is incorrect.

Comment: Hint: `std::string::find` accepts starting position

Comment: @Thesar you could also use could also use something like `  std::replace( s.begin(), s.end(), "x", "y"); `

Comment: @JakeFreeman Yes that worked too. Going to try this and to capitalize the first letter in a new sentence. It might work somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a different overload of [std::string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) that accepts a starting position. Then you start each search ahead of the `'.'` that you found.

Something like this:

```
std::string::size_type pos = 0;

while((pos = s.find(".", pos)) != std::string::npos)
{
    s.replace(pos, 1, ".\n");
    pos += 2; // move past the dot (and the extra '\n')
}
```

This relies on an idiomatic *assign & test* which performs an *assignment* and then *tests* the result:

```
// do the assignment and then test the results
(pos = s.find(".", pos)) != std::string::npos
```

Also note that it is legal with [std::string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) for `pos` to be equal to (but not greater than) `s.size()`.

Comment: So what this means is that we search after pos, which we assign the character ".", and whenever we find it, we replace it with 2 characters .\n and jump over them by adding "2" to the pos? Just want to understand the logic so i can remember it for next time. Thank you!

Comment: @Thesar Yes that is exactly it.

Comment: Cam to think of another issue i have had that i have wanted to implement. This maybe solves it too. To capitalize the first letter in each new line, by capitalizin the first letter after \n, using this overload. You think it would logically work?

Comment: @Thesar Yes you could but it is probably more efficient to make the capital letter change at the same time. You could add that code after the `pos += 2;` to search for the next letter.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a generic function that may do what you want:

```
std::string& replace_all(std::string& str, const std::string& needle,
                         const std::string& replacement)
{
  auto idx = str.find(needle, 0);
  while (idx != std::string::npos) {
    str.replace(idx, needle.size(), replacement);
    idx = str.find(needle, idx + replacement.size());
  }
  return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use the find overload that starts from a position. Something like the following (not tested, just illustrative):

```
if(!str.empty())
{
    size_t pos = 0;
    while(true)
    {
    pos = str.find(pos, '.');
    if(std::string::npos==pos)
    break;
    str.insert(++pos, 1, '\n');
    }
    }
```

Using a condition in the while() would require that it be checked twice (you absolutely need to check after the find), this way there is only one test that can come out different.